# Is it possible to draw two lines of text with drawInRect:withAttributes:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Is it possible to draw multiple lines of text with `drawInRect:withAttributes`? I'm creating a custom daily calendar view that displays events as coloured blocks with a title and subtitle. If I were to write

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *textStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[textStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
[textStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[[self title] drawInRect:_textRect withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle}];
[[self subtitle] drawInRect:_textRect withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle}];
```

then the two lines of text would overlap. Is there any way to draw the subtitle underneath the title?

Comment: yes make a new rect with the new position

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that `_textRect` was unrelated to the coloured block. @rocky